# Limit of the solutions of a linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> Let $A_\epsilon=\begin{bmatrix}1+\epsilon&1 \\ 0 & 1-\epsilon \end{bmatrix}$
>
> Show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $y_\epsilon$ such that $y_\epsilon' = A y_\epsilon$, $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} y_\epsilon$ exists, and $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} y_\epsilon(t)=e^t (0, 1)^T+te^t(1,0)^T$

So the answer is kind of given to me, but I cannot figure out how to prove this. I also cannot figure out why the first vector is $(0,1)^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(0,1)^\top$ is the eigenvector of $A_0$.

If you write the system out, you have to solve
\begin{align}
\dot x&=(1+ϵ)x+y\\
\dot y&=(1-ϵ)y.
\end{align}
This can be solved backwards, $y=y_0e^{(1-ϵ)t}$ and then apply the first order linear DE solution formula to the first equation. With the concrete solutions, the limit argument should be simple enough.